# Ubuntu 16.04 Network Issue, Server Not Found in Mozilla Firefox, Cannot Connect to Slack either

Tags: networking, dual-boot, server, firefox

I am currently running a dual-boot alongside Windows. My windows machine is all working fine, but my Ubuntu 16.04 system seems to be having some network issues. I cannot access certain webpages using any browser, but others are reachable (like Google, Facebook, etc.). Slack is also not connecting, despite my wifi working. Does this have to do with my IPv4 vs IPv6 configuration? I say this because `ping www.google.com` does not work but `ping6 www.google.com` works. Other debugging advice would be helpful as well. I am pretty sure the issues is with the IPv4 connectivity but I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably know more than I do, so take this for what it is worth.

Two days ago, I experienced a similar issue with Ubuntu 16.04. I could print using wi-fi, and Google opened on Firefox but not much else.  I turned off the computer, unplugged it (it's a desktop) and re-plugged it. During the reboot (4.4.0-185-generic) I saw a quick message regarding a "repair". Internet has worked fine since that point. Good luck.